# “They had whatted the car?”

Tags: grammaticality, speech

[The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language](http://www.cambridge.org/uk/linguistics/cgel/) says this:

> Echo ***what*** is syntactically very different from the interrogative pronoun *what*. It can replace words of more or less any category, and can take on the inflectional properties of that category — cf. *You bought three whats?* or even *They had whatted the car?*

CGEL does not use any symbols indicating questionable grammaticality or grammaticality in some dialects only for those examples; therefore, the authors consider the examples correct in all dialects of English, including [International English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_English). As the echo *what* would naturally occur in spoken English (as opposed to written English), it is difficult to ascertain whether the examples would sound idiomatic in major English dialects (e.g. British English, American English) using Google Search. So, my question is:

Which of these are more natural in various spoken English dialects?

> They had *what* the car?
>
> They had *whatted* the car?
>
> You bought three *what*?
>
> You bought three *whats*?

EDIT: Or more generally, what constitutes idiomatic use of echo *what* in British and American English?

Comment: Who in the what now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're going to use *what* as a verb in this way, you have to decline it as usual. So this is correct:

> They had whatted the car?

However, while the above is certainly comprehensible and usable in speech, I would probably just say *They did **what** to the car?*

When using *what* as a pronoun, I prefer keeping it indeclinable:

> They bought three *what*?

However, the plural version is also acceptable:

> They bought three *whats*?

There's no difference of meaning between these. Some speakers may prefer one form, and some the other, but there are no firm rules or conventions about pluralization of *what*.

Comment: Funny...In my dialect, we would just say "They (had) what the car?"...In fact if someone used "whatted," I would probably misunderstand it. Still, it's not something I've paid special attention to, so I won't swear to it.

Comment: -1 because I think the first sentence is wrong. To me *they had what?* is much better than *they had whatted?* but both are OK, conversationally.

Comment: It's hard to gather any kind of evidence on this. [COCA](http://www.americancorpus.org/) contains no instances of *whatted* and I can't find any cases of *had what the (noun)?* either. There are very few cases of echo *what* altogether.

Comment: 'They bought three of *what*?'

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which word you are replacing with *what*, you should usually treat *what* in the same way as the word that it replaces.

So, if you replace *clean* in *They cleaned the car* it would be *They watted the car?*, but if you replace *drive* in *They drove the car* it doesn't have a suffix so it would be *They what the car?*.

The idea is that the "whated" sentence should be as close to the original to be recognisable even with multiple replacements, like for example *They cleaned the car* into *Who whatted the what?*.

Comment: +1 for the point about saying close to the original.  I'd apply this to the noun form of the question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert, but I had the same reaction as JSBangs.  I would say "They *did* what *to* (or other preposition) the car?" or maybe less frequently "They had whatted the car?"

For the record, I'm from the US Northeast.

Answer (score 1):

Both sound natural to me — at least from my ear that normally hears American English when I'm home and British English when I'm abroad. It depends though on the group that's using it — some would use this more than others. If it's been an established within a group — I think it comes off as more natural.